# Login on a user account with empty password

Tags: windows-10

I'm on a situation where a user (lets call it "UserA") account has a empty passoword (I can confirm this with Ophcrack) account is not disabled but i cant log into, tried without entering password just pressing enter but doesnst work.

If i do on terminal:

```
net users UserA somepassword
```

I can log in using `UserA` / `somepassword`.

Comment: How did you remove the password? What message do you see when you can't login?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @Appleoddity i didn't, it a empty by default. it shows wrong username or password

Comment: How do you know Ophcrack is telling you the correct information? Are you reading the correct hash?

Comment: @music2myear the hash that Ophcrack shows is an empty one.

Comment: On windows 7 (not tested on w10) I had similar problems. Local logging in wiothout a password worked. Doing network related stuff **required** a password wand worked after I set one.